# Programmatically checking item in ListView

Tags: android

I need the way to check an item in ListView with choice mode SINGLE from my code. Simply cant't find the method needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29).

Comment: For those reading this almost 5 years later and can't access the broken anchor, the method is `setItemChecked`. @ognian, consider refraining from using links exclusively in your answers.